# cannot reach elements in iframe to hide/remove them

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

[image: inline google map]

Is there any way to remove that panel which is in iframe(embed google maps)

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough question, Google Maps uses a *ton* of different API's and generators. If you have access to the account that created the map, you can generally remove a decent amount of "extras" that aren't necessary in your case. In short, I know it can be done, I'd recommend looking posting the following:

1. How the map is generated
2. Whether or not you have access to the account
3. If you've ever worked with javascript/other methods of replacing display items.

Hope I managed to point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is : no you can't. The reason is you don't have much of a control over `iframes`.

you could try implementing jquery http://jsfiddle.net/85Uww/

but than you will get:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
$("#hmtctl", window.parent.document).css("display","none !important");
```

This is to protect users from code being executed from malicious sites.